# positioning div center of parent div

Tags: html, css

ok so i've been working on this website. mostly just as kind of a proof of concept. i haven't coded a website in quite some time now so this is basically me trying to get back onto the horse as they say.
anyway, i've searched this forum for some time now and i did find quite a few questions very similar to mine. but somehow all the solutions and all the ideas they gave me did not seem to work for me. now maybe i have a typo somewhere making my browser go crazy and misinterpret the code i don't know. what i want to do is create something like a fluid layout with 4 "columns" all being 1/4 of the canvas and full height. in each of these four columns i want to place an image which i want to be center center. so that i can move the image up to the top of the column and have some text at the center on mouseover. thing is i can't seem to find a way to place the image in the center. i tried using  and  containers. i even tried just aligning the  without a container, but it just won't go where i want it. as i mentioned maybe i have a typo somewhere or something. 
any
so this is the html code i use for layout

```
<body>
  <div id="col_home">first text first text</div>
  <div id="col_so"> text text text</div>
  <div id="col_tra">
    <div id="picture">
      <img src="img/Ordner ZU.png" width="100px" height="100px" />
      </div>
    image title
  </div>
  <div id="col_co">last text last text</div>
</body>
```

and this is the css i use for formatting

```
    html {
width: 1024px;
height: 768px;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid;
}

body, div {
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#col_home {
position: relative;
float: left;
left: 0%;
top: 0%;
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
}

#col_so {
position: relative;
float: left;
left: 0%;
top: 0%;
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 1);
}

#col_tra {
position: relative;
float: left;
left: 0%;
top: 0%;
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(255, 204,51);
}

#col_co {
position: relative;
float: left;
left: 0%;
top: 0%;
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
}

#picture {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
clear: left;
}
```

thanks to any- and everyone for help. as i said i'm mostly doing this for fun but still i would like to figure out a possible solution for my learning curve ;). i did run it with id-tags first but for now i don't think it makes a difference at least not in the results i get.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve this is using flexbox. To center a child element in its parent, you can use `justify-content:center;` which aligns an item horizontally, and `align-items:center` - vertically. `flex-flow:row` makes your child elements display in a row, if you want them to display in a column, use `flex-flow:column`. You can see the result by running the snippet by clicking the button below.

```css
 html {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
  margin:auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

body, div {
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
}

#col_home {
  width:25%;
}

#col_so {
  width:25%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 1);
}

#col_tra {
  width:25%;
  flex-flow:column;
  background-color: rgb(255, 204,51);
}

#col_co {
  width:25%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
}
#picture{
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="col_home">first text first text</div>
  <div id="col_so"> text text text</div>
  <div id="col_tra">
    <div id="picture">
      <img src="img/Ordner ZU.png" width="100px" height="100px"/>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="col_co">last text last text</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `float` for column layouts like this is a thing of the past - you really want to use the [flexible box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) (aka "flexbox"). In the example below you can see that setting up the columns takes considerably less CSS code and each column always tries to take up any available space by "flexing." Since there are 4 columns, they all always take up 25% of the space.

Then within any individual column, you can use traditional `relative` positioning with top/left and margin offsets to perfectly center the image:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}


#col2 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 1);
}

#col3 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 204,51);
}

#col4 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
}

#picture {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col" id="col1"></div>
<div class="col" id="col2"></div>
<div class="col" id="col3">
   <div id="picture">
      <img src="img/Ordner ZU.png" width="100px" height="100px" />
      <br>image title  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col" id="col4"></div>
```

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do on mouse hover, but this should get you pretty close. You could also turn each column into a flexing box and try to align the image with `justify` or `align` properties but that might get tricky with hover effects.